# Zoom out in View windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a panel which I generate an image from it and print...but I need to increase the size from it for a better print quality.. Ok, but I wanna increase the size from panel but I need that the user see this panel smaller than it really is...like a zoom out. How can I do this?

Comment: I am not getting your problem .. What I understand you have a panel and in panel background you have set image now you want to zoom in or out that background picture on clicking of zoom in or  zoom out button am I correct ?

Comment: I need zoom the panel, not the picture...

Comment: You can print an image at any size you want with the DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload.  That of course does *not* improve the print quality, that only happens in the Law & Order Crime Labs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simpaly do like this

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
        //panel1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;

    }


    private void btnZoomOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Height = panel1.Size.Height - 1;
        panel1.Width = panel1.Size.Width - 1;
    }

    private void btnZommin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Height = panel1.Size.Height + 1;
        panel1.Width = panel1.Size.Width + 1;
    }
```

Comment: but if I do that, the size from picture changes and the quality too... I need do like photoshop..the size is one and what the user see is other

Comment: I have modified posted code, set panel BackgroundImageLayout as None or Center so it will not change size of background image